# Controlling mouse with Python

Tags: python, mouse

How does one control the mouse cursor in Python, i.e. move it to certain position and click, under Windows?

Comment: Do you nee to make the mouse movement in code without user intervention?

Comment: More information would be *really* helpful...

Comment: I wotk in Windows and i don't use any toolkit. I am really new to Python and I never worked with any GUI before. Where I start from?
What mannual should I read?

Comment: why you need a python to do that, you can do that yourself? on a more serious note, why you need it, what is the purpose, a bit more details would be great

Comment: I recently learned Python on Windows. I started with the tutorials at docs.python.org which were very good.

Comment: If you're trying the answer in a VirtualBox VM and it doesn't seem to work, try disabling mouse pointer integration. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Just FYI if you are using this to keep your machine from locking you could be violating your company or organizations security policy as it is a means of circumventing auto computer locking properties. Ive used this in some places no problem just always make sure to check with your Sys Admins. Ive seen people lose their jobs over minor things like this.

Comment: I also needed keyboard simulation - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2791979/957950) worked the best for me.

Answer (score 378, accepted):

Tested on WinXP, Python 2.6 (3.x also tested) after installing [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) (pywin32-214.win32-py2.6.exe in my case):

```
import win32api, win32con
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
click(10,10)
```

Comment: `win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))` is better to be replaced by `win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, int(x/SCREEN_WIDTH*65535.0), int(y/SCREEN_HEIGHT*65535.0))` in my experience for better integration with other application such as games.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ just take off the MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE flag. for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: can I use this library to control the speed/acceleration of the mouse ?

Comment: This had the advantage of not requiring installation (and associated management review and approval) of non-standard Python modules across 50+ windows boxes (digital signage kiosks).

Comment: tested in `python3.x` works too, feel free to edit the answer

Comment: Any idea how to perform such task without the necessity of using external libraries/tools?

Comment: @Jewenile, if you consider pywin32 to be an "external library/tool", then no.

Comment: It should be noted that this works only in the command line. I tried it in IDLE, and it did not work, while in the command line, it worked perfectly.

Comment: One of the benefits of this answer over [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27046948/1014587) is `win32api` and `win32con` are installed by default in portable packages like WinPython. Quite useful when automating tasks on PCs you don't have admin access on.

Comment: is there a macos equivalent to this library? EDIT: answered below, `PyAutoGUI`

Answer (score 226):

Try with the [PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) module. It's multiplatform.

```py
pip install pyautogui
```

And so:

```py
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(100, 100)
```

It also has other features:

```py
import pyautogui
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 150)
pyautogui.moveRel(0, 10)  # move mouse 10 pixels down
pyautogui.dragTo(100, 150)
pyautogui.dragRel(0, 10)  # drag mouse 10 pixels down
```

This is much easier than going through all the win32con stuff.

Comment: For people trying to install pyautogui, look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892297/problems-importing-python-xlib/18892493 and make sure to put sudo in front of your commands if you have permission problems.

Comment: "PyAutoGUI is slow" because of a safety feature that adds a 0.1 second pause after each call. If your script is out of control, you can slam the mouse to the top-left corner in that 0.1 seconds to stop it. To disable this, run pyautogui.PAUSE = 0 (though this is not recommended, because you can't use the mouse/keyboard to stop the script.)

Comment: Also, PyAutoGUI does not play well with more than 1 monitors: https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/162

Comment: PyAutoGUI does work with multiple monitors on Windows (you use negative coordinates for other screens) but not yet on mac/linux. It also currently has no way of detecting the monitor layout. So, it works, but tenuously.

Answer (score 91):

You can use `win32api` or `ctypes` module to use win32 apis for controlling mouse or any gui

Here is a fun example to control mouse using win32api:

```
import win32api
import time
import math

for i in range(500):
    x = int(500+math.sin(math.pi*i/100)*500)
    y = int(500+math.cos(i)*100)
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    time.sleep(.01)
```

A click using ctypes:

```
import ctypes

# see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260(VS.85).aspx for details
ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(100, 20)
ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0,0) # left down
ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0,0) # left up
```

Comment: your ctypes code worked for me without any additional libraries! (python 2.6 on windows 7)

Comment: Thank you!  I can't stand that there are like 3 3rd party libraries that you can do this with, however all 3 libraries are maddening to install or troubleshoot.  This ctypes solution is the first native python solution and it works better than every other I have come across.

Comment: Where is the documentation for `SetCursorPos`?

Comment: Can confirm still works without any additional libraries. (python 3.7.4 win 10)

Answer (score 60):

As of **2022**, you can use [mouse](https://github.com/boppreh/mouse):

```
import mouse
mouse.move("500", "500")
mouse.click() # default to left click
# mouse.right_click()
# mouse.double_click(button='left')
# mouse.double_click(button='right')
# mouse.press(button='left')
# mouse.release(button='left')
```

### [Full Api documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/mouse#api)

Features

- Global event hook on all mice devices (captures events regardless of
  focus).
- Listen and sends mouse events.
- Works with **Windows and Linux** (requires sudo).
- Pure Python, no C modules to be compiled.
- Zero dependencies. Trivial to install and deploy, just copy the
  files.
- Python 2 / 3
- Includes high level API (e.g. record and play).
- Events automatically captured in separate thread, doesn't block main
  program.
- Tested and documented.

---

Installation

- Windows:  `pip install mouse`
- Linux:  `sudo pip install mouse`

Comment: You can also do `mouse.move("500", "500", False)` to move relatively.

Comment: is it possible to capture a specific window and simulate mouse click on it?

Comment: what's the difference with pynput? it also hooks events with ctypes and uses Quartz for mac

Comment: Nice one, doesn't work with macos `OSError: Unsupported platform 'Darwin'`

Answer (score 28):

Another option is to use the cross-platform [AutoPy package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopy/0.51). This package has two different options for moving the mouse:

This code snippet will instantly move the cursor to position (200,200):

```
import autopy
autopy.mouse.move(200,200)
```

If you instead want the cursor to visibly move across the screen to a given location, you can use the smooth_move command:

```
import autopy
autopy.mouse.smooth_move(200,200)
```

Comment: Upvoting particularly for python 3.7 users on apple silicon (M2), since autopy is the only package that seems to be working (importing pyautogui seems to yield an `ObjC Class 'b'NSEvent'' couldn't be found` despite my bests attempts to fix it)

Answer (score 24):

#### Linux

```
from Xlib import X, display
d = display.Display()
s = d.screen()
root = s.root
root.warp_pointer(300,300)
d.sync()
```

Source: [Python mouse move in 5 lines of code (Linux only)](http://danielbaggio.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/python-mouse-move-in-5-lines-of-code.html).

Comment: A google for "Python controlling mouse movement" now finds this page, how meta.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, since the question also asked to simulate mouse clicks, I'll add : `Xlib.ext.xtest.fake_input(d, X.ButtonPress, 1); d.sync(); time.sleep(0.001); Xlib.ext.xtest.fake_input(d, X.ButtonRelease, 1); d.sync();` the sleep() call between press and release may or may not be required depending on the target application.

Comment: @Copas - Results appearing in your Google mean nothing. You're in a bubble. This shows up in a DuckDuckGo search for the same term - that's  something real. That's something everyone else can reproduce and see for themselves. That's meta.

Comment: To control mouse in a VNC session, you need the display number as well like "d = display.Display(':1')" where :1 is the display number.

Answer (score 20):

Check out the cross platform PyMouse: https://github.com/pepijndevos/PyMouse/

Comment: PyMouse has been superseded with [PyUserInput](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput), fits exactly the request, simple to use and cross platform. Big +1

Comment: @user336851, do you know how to `tap space` and `tap screen shot key` by using PyUswerInput?

Comment: @user336851, At this time `PyUserInput` is broken.  Can't say if it works well or not because I can't even get it to install due to broken dependencies.

Answer (score 15):

[Pynput](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput) is the best solution I have found, both for Windows and for Mac. Super easy to program, and works very well.

For example,

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()

# Read pointer position
print('The current pointer position is {0}'.format(
    mouse.position))

# Set pointer position
mouse.position = (10, 20)
print('Now we have moved it to {0}'.format(
    mouse.position))

# Move pointer relative to current position
mouse.move(5, -5)

# Press and release
mouse.press(Button.left)
mouse.release(Button.left)

# Double click; this is different from pressing and releasing
# twice on Mac OSX
mouse.click(Button.left, 2)

# Scroll two steps down
mouse.scroll(0, 2)
```

Comment: I just tried to run an old program on a Windows computer and it did not work, so please do test it out before using. This program at least claims to support both.

Comment: I did some testing, and it turns out that my issue was that on Mac, having floats as coordinate values works just fine, but on Windows, the coordinates need to be integers. This module is cross-platform.

Comment: I have added an Issue to the github repository to see if they can improve it: https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/79

Comment: **It looks like the issue has since been fixed.**

Answer (score 13):

Quick and dirty function that'll left click wherever `clicks` times on Windows 7 using the [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) library. No downloads required.

```
import ctypes

SetCursorPos = ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos
mouse_event = ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event

def left_click(x, y, clicks=1):
  SetCursorPos(x, y)
  for i in xrange(clicks):
   mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
   mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0, 0)

left_click(200, 200) #left clicks at 200, 200 on your screen. Was able to send 10k clicks instantly.
```

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative would be [mouse library](https://github.com/boppreh/mouse), I personally use it as it is relatively simple and cross-platform.

Here is how you can use it:

```
import mouse
# move 100 right and 100 down with a duration of 0.5 seconds
mouse.move(100, 100, absolute=False, duration=0.5)
# left click
mouse.click('left')
# right click
mouse.click('right')
```

Here is the source: [How to Control your Mouse in Python](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/control-mouse-python)

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer worked for me but it was unstable (sometimes clicks wouldn't regsiter) so I added an additional **MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP** . Then it was working  reliably

```
import win32api, win32con
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0) 
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
click(10,10)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import ctypes
from time import sleep

SetCursorPos = ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos
print("Woohoo!\nTake Rest!\nMouse pointer will keep moving!\n\nPress ctrl+c to stop...!")
while True:
    SetCursorPos(300, 300)
    sleep(2)
    SetCursorPos(500, 500)
    sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to move the mouse, use this:

```py
import pyautogui
pyautogui.moveTo(x,y)
```

If you want to click, use this:

```py
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(x,y)
```

If you don't have `pyautogui` installed, you must have python attached to CMD. Go to CMD and write: `pip install pyautogui`

This will install `pyautogui` for Python 2.x.

For Python 3.x, you will probably have to use `pip3 install pyautogui` or `python3 -m pip install pyautogui`.

Comment: You'll want to call `pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)` because `move()` moves the cursor relative to its current position.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood your original comment. Yes, both functions work. `moveTo()` moves to an absolute location, while `move()` moves relative to the current cursor location.

Answer (score 2):

very easy 
1- install pakage :

```
pip install mouse
```

2- add library to project :

```
import mouse
```

3- use it for example :

```
mouse.right_click()
```

in this url describe all function that you can use it :

https://github.com/boppreh/mouse

Comment: It's even has MAC support now. Direct pip install will not work for MAC. You need to install in MAC by following commands:

pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz
pip install git+https://github.com/boppreh/mouse.git

Answer (score 2):

**Move Mouse Randomly On Screen**

It will move the mouse randomly on screen according to your screen resolution.
check code below.

Install `pip install pyautogui` using this command.

```
import pyautogui
import time
import random as rnd

#calculate height and width of screen
w, h = list(pyautogui.size())[0], list(pyautogui.size())[1]

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    #move mouse at random location in screen, change it to your preference
    pyautogui.moveTo(rnd.randrange(0, w), 
                     rnd.randrange(0, h))#, duration = 0.1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to work with games. As explained in this post https://www.learncodebygaming.com/blog/pyautogui-not-working-use-directinput, some games like Minecraft or Fortnite have their own way of registering mouse / keyboard events. The way to control mouse and keyboard events is by using the **brand new** PyDirectInput library. Their github repository is https://github.com/learncodebygaming/pydirectinput, and has a lot of great information.
Here's a quick code that does a mouse loop, and clicks:

```py
import pydirectinput  # pip install pydirectinput


pydirectinput.moveTo(0, 500)
pydirectinput.click()
```

Comment: This works with synergy integrated multi desktops and VLC Directshow input. Clever AF.

Answer (score 0):

try using pyautogui, easy and also you can simulate pressing keys on keaboard

Answer (score 0):

Try Clicknium,
https://www.clicknium.com/documents/references/python/mouse/
It can control the mouse and keyboard and help you to locate the UI elements in web browsers and desktop applications.

This is a sample of moving the mouse along a circle

```
from time import sleep
import math
from clicknium import clicknium as cc
def circle():
    a,b = cc.mouse.position()
    w = 20  
    m = (2*math.pi)/w 
    r = 200      

    while 1:    
        for i in range(0, w+1):
            x = int(a+r*math.sin(m*i))  
            y = int(b+r*math.cos(m*i))
            cc.mouse.move(x,y)
            sleep(0.2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    circle()
```

Answer (score -1):

The reality is automating mouse and keyboard using python is a bit complicated. Specially if you're building in Linux.
Anyways...

Do you really need to do it in Python, tho?
Cause there's an easier way to do it, if you're in Windows.
Just use AutoHotkey scripting language

Comment: Questions for more information should be posted as comments. Please use the answer box for solutions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34396428)