# Simulate mouse click/Detect color under cursor in Python

Tags: python, colors, mouse

I am very new to python. I am trying to write a program that will click the mouse at (x, y), move it to (a, b), and then wait until the color under the mouse is a certain color, lets say #fff. When it is that color, it clicks again and then repeats.

I cannot find a good API for mouse related stuff for python.

Comment: You can find some info on clicking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The API for simulating mouse events depends on your platform. I don't know any cross-platform solution.

On Windows, you can access the Win32 API thanks to ctypes. see [mouse_event on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260%28VS.85%29.aspx). You may also be interested by [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.openqa.org/)

For getting the color under the mouse, you need the mouse position. See [GetCursorPos on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390%28VS.85%29.aspx). Then if your app has an API for getting the color at this position you can use it. If not, you can try to grab a small portion of the screen around the cursor and to use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) for getting the colors of every pixel in this area. I think that PIL screen capture is only working on Windows paltform but I am not sure.

I am using the following function for a similar need:

```
def grab_main_color(self, rect, max_colors=256):
    """returns a tuple with the RGB value of the most present color in the given rect"""
    img=ImageGrab.grab(rect)
    colors = img.getcolors(max_colors)
    max_occurence, most_present = 0, 0
    try:
        for c in colors:
            if c[0] > max_occurence:
                (max_occurence, most_present) = c
        return most_present
    except TypeError:
        raise Exception("Too many colors in the given rect")
```

Answer (score -1):

if you're on Windows, then, for this kind of thing, you really want to try [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com). It's not python, but it is **extremely powerful** for doing this kind of thing on a Windows machine. The user community is extremely helpful, also. Check out their "ask for help" forum.