# Cannot programmatically move mouse cursor in VirtualBox

Tags: python, winapi, virtualbox

I'm trying to use this Python code:

```
import math
import win32api
for i in xrange(500):
    x = 500 + math.sin(math.pi * i / 100) * 500
    y = 500 + math.cos(i) * 100
    x, y = int(x), int(y)
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    time.sleep(.01)
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python) to move the mouse cursor in an XP VirtualBox. The mouse icon will flicker to the appropriate graphic (when it hits the edge of a window it turns into the **<->** resize image, for instance), but it doesn't actually move the visible cursor. I can move the mouse around while the code is running. Same result using the `ctypes` example in the above link. It works fine in the Win7 host.

I have Guest Additions installed, if that matters.

Comment: Sounds like a VirtualBox issue (having little to do with Python).

Comment: Updated title to reflect that.

Comment: I've seen the same with Ms Virtual PC (no python). Was only happening when "use pointer integration" setting was active (when the guest was not clipping the cursor).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to import the win32api.

Comment: The `import` was probably just left out of the example code -- if that was the problem it wouldn't run at all giving a `NameError: name 'win32api' is not defined` instead.