# Problems importing python-Xlib

Tags: python, module, dependencies

I installed a new module and it appears as if one of its dependencies was not already installed. The module is called Xlib.display.
Here is the error message I received:

```
from Xlib.display import Display
ImportError: No module named Xlib.display
```

Where can I find this module that I am apparently lacking? Google yielded no leads.

"Edit: I already have that sourceforge module downloaded but I still get the same results.

Comment: Uh... *try* Google before saying it didn't help... http://www.google.com/search?q=python+xlib

Comment: So you downloaded it. Did you install it?

Comment: It loads fine for me in Python 2, just not Python 3

Answer (score 21):

Please try.

This shall install Xlib 
`sudo apt-get install  python-xlib`

Then you can check

`>>from Xlib.display import Display`

To install PyMouse if you want to control and capture mouse events please use:

`sudo easy_install https://github.com/pepijndevos/PyMouse/zipball/master`

Answer (score 15):

Below worked for me!

```
pip install python3_xlib
```

I have also used pyuserinput for automation which requires this.

Comment: I did `pip install python-xlib` inside virtualenv. Great!

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem, but the solutions above didn't work for me. Since I had installed python through the anaconda package, when I used:

```
sudo apt-get install  python-xlib
```

Xlib was still undetectable by python2. The solution in my case was to use:

```
anaconda search -t conda python-xlib
```

Then find the package from the anaconda api, mine was erik/python-xlib. Install it using:

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/erik python-xlib
```

Then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian systems install [python-xlib](http://packages.debian.org/en/squeeze/python-xlib).

On other systems there's a high probability that the package carries the same name.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the Xlib library works in Python 3.

[Source](https://github.com/alexer/python-xlib/blob/master/README):

> **Requirements**
>
> The Python X Library requires Python 1.5.2 or newer.  It has been tested to various extents with Python 1.5.2 and 2.0 through 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly cant explain why this works... but here is the command that got it working for me.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-xlib
```

Should not work because xlib apparently does not work with python 3.x, but everything installed alright, so I'm not complaining!

Comment: 2021-10-12 worked for me on xubuntu 21.04, when the same command without the "3" failed.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same answer, however after some more digging it seems that [XCB (X protocol C-language Binding)](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/) will obsolete Xlib in general. From the XCB website:

> The X protocol C-language Binding (XCB) is a replacement for Xlib featuring a small footprint, latency hiding, direct access to the protocol, improved threading support, and extensibility.

Fortunately there are python bindings available as **python-xpyb in apt** or [**xpyb on PyPi**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xpyb). I've not gotten that far in my project so I haven't tested if this works with Python3, but this is probably the way to go and the proper place to file any Python3 support bugs if necessary.

Comment: python-xlib is not a wrapper for the C-language Xlib library, it is a pure-python implementation of the X protocol. As such, the XCB intending to replace the C-language Xlib has no effect on the python-xlib library.

Answer (score 0):

### Scenario:

I was trying to use screenshot functionalities of `pyautogui` package. I was getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_screenshot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File ".../miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_x11 as platformModule
  File ".../miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Xlib.display import Display
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Xlib'
```

Python code (`test_screenshot.py`):

```
import pyautogui
img = pyautogui.screenshot('test.png')
```

**Environment:**

- Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS)
- conda 4.5.11
- Python 3.7 (Miniconda)
- requirements.txt:

  ```
  certifi==2019.3.9
  Pillow==5.4.1
  PyAutoGUI==0.9.42
  PyGetWindow==0.0.4
  PyMsgBox==1.0.6
  PyRect==0.1.4
  PyScreeze==0.1.20
  PyTweening==1.0.3
  ```

### Solution:

I installed `python-xlib` package in the conda environment using:

```
pip install python-xlib
```

Now `test_screenshot.py` is running without any error.

Updated `requirements.txt`:

```
certifi==2019.3.9
Pillow==5.4.1
PyAutoGUI==0.9.42
PyGetWindow==0.0.4
PyMsgBox==1.0.6
PyRect==0.1.4
PyScreeze==0.1.20
python-xlib==0.25
PyTweening==1.0.3
six==1.12.0
```