# How can I cause Chrome to have focus and refresh a given page from outside of Chrome? In C#/.NET

Tags: google-chrome, macros, interop

How can I duplicate the functionality of this [sublime script](https://github.com/gcollazo/BrowserRefresh-Sublime/blob/master/BrowserRefresh.py)?  The code itself says pretty much what I'd like to do:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell the active tab of its first window
    reload
end tell
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
```

I'd like to do this without using some kind of testing framework/driver.  Just to understand  fundamentally what is going on behind this code. If it's too much work then I'll probably punt and use a Selenium Driver.  I'm guessing that some library that Python has made this kind of thing trivial?  And, of course, add a macro to Visual Studio/Emacs (or something) to produce the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Just send Ctrl-R to google chrome. There is one API for python [here](http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/), and that *should* be enough. It should work, but it might get snagged somewhere else,  just send a mouse click using the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python). There really isn't any simple solution unless you have an api for chrome in particular. If you want that, there's a guide [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html).
It should not be too complicated, seems like a simple enough operation to merit its own place in the convenient parts of the API.