# Linux - Simulating mouse clicks with Python

Tags: python, linux, mouse

I want to simulate mouse clicks in Python (and if it is possible, also keyboard inputs) in a Linux system (Ubuntu), so I am able to create a macro for an external program.

I have researched a bit, and found questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python) which use win32api or ctypes to do the job. But since I am working in Ubuntu, those doesn't fit for me.

I also found [Xaut](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xautomation/) (former Xautomation), which is said to simulate mouse and keyboard interactions over Linux systems. But it is hard to install for me, and it lacks documentation and examples anyway.

I really like the win32api solution, it's very simple. Isn't there any similar solution for Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike Windows, Linux is a secure system by design so injecting/intercepting user events isn't simple :-)

But there are tools which can do the same on Linux (at least when they have xauth credentials, so no snooping/cracking other users on the same computer). Try [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml) which offers a wide range of commands to find and select windows and then send events to them.

xdotool is available for most Linux distributions (debian and [rpm based](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&limit=1&srodzaj=3&dl=40&search=xdotool)).

Note: For security reasons, synthetic events in X11 have a flag set and some software ignores all events with this flag.

Comment: If I'm going to leave the Python script idea and embracing a tool like this, wouldn't be better to use some macro creator with a GUI? xdotool looks too simple

Comment: Use Python to build a wrapper for the script. This way, you can create yourself a macro generator and executor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
import pyautogui 
x= #x position
y= #y position
pyautogui.click(x,y)
```

To install pyautogui visit the official installation page documentation: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

To write text automatically use this:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.write('write this example')
```