# Program that clicks 3 buttons in a web app in a specified order

Tags: button

I was wondering if i can write a program that clicks some buttons in a specified order in a web app or a web site. For example click Autos then weather then sports in http://www.bbc.co.uk/ with that order.
I have made some search but i didn't find anything about that.
I don't know even in what language i can write it or how to start.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about "browser automation."  A popular tool for that is Selenium: http://docs.seleniumhq.org

Comment: look for windows automation, or web app testing software. Me I'd just host a webcontrol and hit the three urls

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Here are 2 possible ways you can take:

- Java with [Robot class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)
- Python with [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) or see [example from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python)

Java example:

```
Robot r=new Robot();
r.mouseMove(x,y);
r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```