# Python win32api LEFTDOWN LEFTUP not clicking

Tags: python

When running this .py script, it doesn't return any error and does print "Click." but it doesn't actually click.

```
import os, sys
import time
import win32api, win32con

def leftClick():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)
    print "Click."    

def main():
    leftClick()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python

Comment: The answer to that question is basically what I'm using now, just not using set co-ordinates?