# Mouse click inside a specifc window or application using python

Tags: python-2.7, code-injection

How does one inject into an application to simulate a mouse click in a window, even if it isn't on top or in focus, using `python 2.7` ?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python

Comment: Thanks, but I guess that method just clicks a coordinate on the screen, I want it to click in a specific application, even if it's not on top.

Comment: i am also interested in this