# Find number in a variable python

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, click

I am trying to make a Twitch plays Roller Coaster Tycoon 2 (for fun) with help from [this site](http://www.wituz.com/tutorial-make-your-own-twitch-plays-stream.html) and a slightly modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python) to click on the screen. What I want to do is: if a person writes for example `!click 10 10`, it will click at position 10 10, but I don't know how to do that.
My dad said that I have to find a way to find those numbers and turn them in to a variable. I've already wrote a bit to turn the text into a variable.

Define `clickMSG`:

```
clickMSG = ""
```

Code to detect message:

```
if "!click" in msg:
    clickMSG = msg
```

How can I find those numbers and turn them into the variables `xpos` and `ypos` if, for example, the message is `!click 50 10`?

Comment: consider using `msg.split()`, that will produce the list ['!click', '10', '10']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without re (regular expression), here is my code:

```
msg = "!click 10 10"
clickMSG = ""

if "!click" in msg:
    clickMSG = msg.strip("!click ")  # removes "!click" from msg
    xpos, ypos = clickMSG.split()
    xpos = int(xpos)    # 
    ypos = int(ypos)    # converts string (e.g. "10") to number (e.g. 10)
    print(xpos)
    print(ypos)
```

Comment: Thanks. I already solved it thanks to @chapelo 's comment, but you used a better way to split things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re

regex = re.compile('.* (\d+) (\d+')

if "!click" in msg:
    clickMSG = msg
    xpos, ypos = map(int, regex.match(msg).groups())
```

`.` means any character, and `*` means zero or more times.  Therefore, `.*` is just however many of whatever characters are there (in this case, `"!click"`).  The `\d` means a digit, and `+` means one or more times.  We add parentheses so that it becomes a group in the regex.  We have two of those groups: `'50'` and `'10'`.  We then convert them to integers with `map(int, ...)`, and assign `xpos` and `ypos` to them.