# PyAutoGui [WinError 2] after coverting the script to exe using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, pyautogui

I just wanted to ask your help with my problem below.
My code is working perfectly but after converting it to `.exe` using `PyInstaller`, I will encounter `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]`.

Kindly suggest how I can fix it.

[image: FileNotFound:[WinError 2]]

Code:

```
import pyautogui, time

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(30)
        pyautogui.dragRel(1,0)
        pyautogui.dragRel(-1,0)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Done')
```

Comment: Do you convert it to a singlefile exe or a folder with the exe and some files?

Comment: I tried both but it wont work.

Comment: Continue testing with the folder executable first. Have you tried https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/If-Things-Go-Wrong and https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/How-to-Report-Bugs#make-sure-everything-is-packaged-correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with PyAutoGUI and PyInstaller and could not get the clicking to work. Moving the mouse and the image recognition seem to work though.

Thanks to this post right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1181539/2658408) I found a "workaround":

Instead of using the **pyautogoi.click()** method, I'm using a similar method from **ctypes**.

```
import ctypes
```

I exchanged the pyautogui.click() calls with

```
# see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260(VS.85).aspx for details
ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0,0) # left down
ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0,0) # left up
```

For double clicking I just call those two methods twice.