# Python low level mouse clicks

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

**Using Windows 10 64bit**

I'm trying to learn how to code in python and I decided to make my first program a simple bot for a game.

The game is a downloadable game.

The goal is for my mouse to click a button at coordinates (200, 200)

I have tried many different ways to get this to work.

I've tried...

- [PyAutoGui](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks)
- [pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1181538/4310761)
- [ctypes](https://gist.github.com/hrwatahiki/ac9fbe414d2608893210)

PyAutoGui implementation

`pyautogui.click(200, 200)`

pywin32 implementation

```
import win32api, win32con
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
click(10,10)
```

Any ideas? From what I understand I need to use a low level driver?

I just don't understand how to emulate it as if a real mouse was clicking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python win32 simulate click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964051/python-win32-simulate-click)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Game isn't detecting mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39990565/game-isnt-detecting-mouse-click)

Answer (score 0):

try pyautogui.mouseDown() or pyautogui.mouseUp() instead...
info: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that you set the raw input checkbox in game settings for the mouse. I had the same issue with CSGO

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work with your game but you can use [PyUserInput](https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput#how-to-get-started).