# Python 3.6.0 how to set point on screen and auto click with delay

Tags: python-3.6

I'm new in programming and learning by my self using python 3.6.0 win 32bit ver.

I'm trying to make program where I can set point for mouse on screen using pixels and then click and wait lets say 2 sec. and click again.

Comment: This question might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python

Comment: I was trying that but I had problems to install pygame on new ver. of python 3.6.0 before this I was using python 3.2.3 and I had no problems to install pygame but now it dosent want to install actualy I need help on that to :( I had about 1 year break from python and I have forget allot if someone knows how to do that please tell  me too thanks for answers

Comment: I'm confused. None of the answers at the [link I mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1181464/) used pygame. The only other aspect that isn't answered there is the delay. The delay is done by importing the time module(`import time`), and using `time.sleep(2)` for 2 seconds, which can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/510348/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling mouse with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python)