# Python 3 - Automatically put file under pressed cursor for dragging into other application

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, mouse, self-modifying

I want to write a workflow improving script for an application I use. The issue is the target application is only accepting files that are moved onto it via drag and drop. The Source from where I am dragging is though not dragging the actual file handler but a string of xml-data (which includes the file location).

Getting the exact string of the file location is no problem, however, I can't figure out a way to "move" this file automatically under the pressed mouse cursor of the user in order to enable drag and drop working.

The script would need to work on Windows, are there any options in Python avaiable to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at PyAutoGUI or the other recommendations here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python . I'm not sure it's really what you want, but you can move the mouse faster than a human can see to click and drag an item back to where the "expected" position is.