# Selenium Button Selector and Click

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to automate the restart of my router using Selenium on Python. Everything is working fine except for the last step, which is locating the restart button and click it!

I have tried to locate it by (id, css_selector, name, value, xpath), but nothing seemed to work.

Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://192.168.100.1')

english = driver.find_element_by_id("English")
english.click()

usr = "username"
pwd = "password"

usrname_box = driver.find_element_by_id("txt_Username")
usrname_box.send_keys(usr)

pwd_box = driver.find_element_by_id("txt_Password")
pwd_box.send_keys(pwd)

submit_ = driver.find_element_by_id("button")
submit_.click()
sleep(1)


resetit = driver.find_element_by_name("maindiv_reset")
resetit.click()
sleep(1)

# This is the one I want to locate
reboot = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='btnReboot']")
reboot.click()
```

And this is the HTML code for the target button:

```
<input class="ApplyButtoncss buttonwidth_150px" name="btnReboot" id="btnReboot" type="button" onclick="Reboot()" bindtext="s0603" value="Restart">
```

When trying anything, I get the error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: (WHATEVER I TRY)
```

A Screenshot of the HTML Page:

[image: HTML Page]

Thank you all for your help in advance.

Comment: Does the "Roboot" button appear after clicking the "Reset" button?

Comment: Yes, it is showing and I can click it manually, but the python code can't reach it.

Comment: That's not quite what I asked. If the Reboot button appears dynamically **after** clicking the Reset button then that can affect the solution to your problem.

Comment: It shows up right after clicking the `System Tools` tab, which is `resetit` in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is an [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to locate and `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ApplyButtoncss.buttonwidth_150px#btnReboot[value='Restart']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='ApplyButtoncss buttonwidth_150px' and @id='btnReboot'][@value='Restart']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I suspect this is the right answer. Sounds like a race condition between selenuim and JavaScript.

Comment: The code produced the error: `TimeoutException: Message: ` for both (CSS selector and XPath). It takes a moment before running into this error.

Comment: Can I excute a javascript code ( got it from the button javascript file ) using the `driver.execute_script(javascript)`, when I tried it, it gave me an error saying `JavascriptException: Message: SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'` and I am not sure if what I am doing is right!?

Comment: @SoulSA Of coarse we do have the `execute_script()` option but that should be the last resort. However _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _ExpectedConditions_. Can you debug your code through `find_element_by_*` in-conjunction with `time.sleep()` and if you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations? Additionally, check if the element is within an `<iframe>` tag.

Comment: @DebanjanB I solved the problem thanks to your reply. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thy this one:

```
reboot = driver.find_element_by_name("btnReboot")
reboot.click()
```

Comment: Same issue:
`NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="btnReboot"]`

Comment: try using: 
resetit = driver.find_element_by_class("ApplyButtoncss buttonwidth_150px")
or
resetit = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ApplyButtoncss buttonwidth_150px")

Comment: It would be easier if the website was public and we can try the script by ourselves but try this one: driver.execute_script("Reboot()")

Comment: I tried it, it gave me `JavascriptException: Message: ReferenceError: Reboot is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

As the target button was included in `iframe`, I used the following method to solve the problem:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("frameContent")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.find_element_by_id('btnReboot').click()
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
```

Thanks a lot to everyone tried to help, especially to [DebanjanB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/debanjanb)

Answer (score -1):

As a last ditch solution you can tell Python to click the Restart button assuming you can find the pixel (X, Y) coordinates on the screen and assuming the Firefox browser does not shift when running the script. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1181538/4730972).