# How to make my mouse click randomly in a set box?

Tags: python, winapi, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to have my mouse click randomly along a bar within a program to set data. I'm not sure how to do it. I have tried setting a box inside the leftClick at the bottom but that unsurprisingly didn't work. I'm very new to python and I'm doing this for an aerospace engineering class I'm taking.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import os
import time
import win32api, win32con
import random

# Globals
# ----------------

x_pad = 14
y_pad = 70

def screenGrab():
    box = (x_pad+1,y_pad+1,x_pad+1508,y_pad+258)
    im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\full_snap__' + str(int(time.time())) + '.png', 'PNG')

def main():
    screenGrab()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

"""
Omitted code not necessary for this part
"""

def get_cords():
    x,y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    x = x - x_pad
    y = y - y_pad

def startGame():
    #location of first bar
    mousePos((33,125))
    leftClick(
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @PeptideWitch, but more "Python" in mouse event.

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import random

def click_box(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max):
    new_x = random.uniform(x_min, x_max)
    new_y = random.uniform(y_min, y_max)
    print(new_x,new_y)
    mouse = Controller()
    mouse.position = (new_x, new_y)
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [python's inbuilt random.randrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), which returns a value between your specified coordinates, say (33 and 124). You will want to feed in the outer limits of the box you make and then get python to return a random value between those two spaces.

Then, try [something like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python):

```
def click_box(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max):
    new_x = random.randrange(x_min, x_max+1)
    new_y = random.randrange(y_min, y_max+1)
    win32api.SetCursorPos((new_x,new_y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,new_x,new_y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,new_x,new_y,0,0)
```

Comment: This is missing the [`MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) flag. Once you add it, you're going to have to calculate normalized coordinates, too. This is also missing an opportunity to prevent a bug by calling [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput), as the documentation explains.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, we use `win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, int(x/SCREEN_WIDTH*65535.0), int(y/SCREEN_HEIGHT*65535.0))` instead of setting the cursor position. I'm not sure how to wrap this inside of the `SendInput` function, though.

Comment: IInspectable means [`mouse_event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) function has been superseded by `SendInput` according to the document.

Comment: The important point here is, that you want to make sure to inject compound information into the input stream atomically, without opening a window of opportunity to have it interspersed with input from other sources. As for the other point: Yes, that's a partial implementation calculating normalized coordinates. It's missing the part that's retrieving the overall geometry, and I don't know which size to use in case of a multi-monitor setup.