# How to skip error message pop-up with subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using `subprocess` in `Python` to call an external program on WINDOWS. I control the process with `ThreadPool` so that I can limit it to max 6 processes at the same time, and new process continuously began when one was done.

Codes as below:

```py
### some codes above

### Code of Subprocess Part

from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

def FAST_worker(file):
    p = subprocess.Popen([r'E:/pyworkspace/FAST/FAST_RV_W64.exe', file],
                         cwd = r'E:/pyworkspace/FAST/',
                         shell = True)
    p.wait()

# List of *.in filenames
FAST_in_pathname_li = [
    '334.in',
    '893.in',
    '9527.in',
    ...
    '114514.in',
    '1919810.in',
]

# Limit max 6 processes at same time
with Pool(processes = 6) as pool:
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(FAST_worker, FAST_in_pathname_li):
        pass

### some codes below
```

I got problem when **the external program unexpectedly terminated and showed error message pop-up**. Though the other 5 processes still kept going, the whole progress will finally get stuck at the "subprocess part" and couldn't go forward anymore. (unless I came to my desk and manually clicked "Shut down the program")

What I want to know is how can I avoid the pop-up and make the whole script process keep going, like bypass the error message or something, rather than manual click, in order to avoid wasting time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we don't know enough about the program `FAST_worker` is calling, I'll assume you already checked there isn't any "kill on error" or "quiet" mode that would be more convenient to use in a script.

My two cents: maybe you can setup a timeout on the worker execution, so that a stuck process is killed automatically after a certain delay.

Building on the snippet provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10012262/7002298), here is a draft:

```py
from threading import Timer

def FAST_worker(file, timeout_sec):
    def kill_proc():
        """called by the Timer thread upon expiration"""
        p.kill()
        # maybe add task to list of failed task, for tracability

    p = subprocess.Popen([r'E:/pyworkspace/FAST/FAST_RV_W64.exe', file],
                         cwd = r'E:/pyworkspace/FAST/',
                         shell = True)
    # setup timer to kill the process after a timeout
    timer = Timer(timeout_sec, kill_proc)
    try:
        timer.start()
        stdout, stderr = p.wait()
    finally:
        timer.cancel()
```

Note that there are also GUI automation libraries in python that can do the clicking for you, but that is likely to be more tedious to program:

- [tutorial for pyAutoGui](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/)
- [SO question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python)

Comment: I've tried applying code above into my script, but the behavior of the process became weird. (sorry for not know how to explain) Maybe I'll contact with the writer of the `FAST_RV_W64.exe` program. Still thanks for your help.