# Click on OK WinForm button using python3 code

Tags: python-3.x, winforms

I have `Winform` application that display `OkCancel` `MessageBox` on start.
I want to click on "OK" button using python3 code, Is It possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python

Comment: you can do mouse clicks using python, if you can figure out where to click then it should be possible

Comment: to detect the window use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266281/obtain-active-window-using-python