# How can I control the Edge web browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, automation, webautomation

I would like to control an edge browser without an interface like selenium, because it prevents me from accessing our company's website for security reasons.

All I need to do is automate the opening of my web browser -> access to the desired website -> copy and paste the desired content into the fields that I will assign to it.

I will be more than satisfied for any useful answer.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You could open Microsoft Edge by using cmd:

```
start msedge <websiteURL>
```

To code this in python, we could use ***subprocess library***.

```
import subprocess as sub

sub.run(["start"], ["msedge"], "<websiteURL>"])
```

And here comes the hard part. I couldn't find any API to control Edge browser, all I can think of is taking control of mouse and keyboard using libraries like:

- pywin32 [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python]
- pyautogui [[Docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)]

If you are not using Edge Browser on daily basis, you could open browser window to be max size, so you would have to worry about mouse movements being displaced.